# 'Push' files from one linux machine to another via SSH

Tags: linux, command-line, file-management

I have 2 linux machines, one (1st) containing about 8 GB of small files (images, flv etc)

I need to upload/push those files to the other machine (2nd).

I would use rsync to pull them down to the 2nd machine however the 1st machine (containing the files) has file wall rules that I cannot circumvent therefore I cannot ssh into it from the 2nd machine.

Comment: So why can't you use rsync to do the pushing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsync` can operate in either direction; either pulling files or pushing them. Since you can't pull from machine 1, why not push from machine 1 to machine 2? The syntax for rsync is just like `scp`.

```
rsync options source destination
```

So, in your case, you might...

```
rsync -azv ~/my_folder chris@machine2.local:~
```

This will copy `~/my_folder/` to the same location on machine 2.

You could use scp with the `-r` flag here as well, but `rsync` is more suited for the task.